# iOS UISearchbar in UIToolbar, show search result not popover in iPad

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uitoolbar, popover

I'm use iPad  UISearchbar embed in UIToolbar, the search result will show in the UIPopover

but use iPhone, it's show in same table view

I want to search result show in the same table view, How can I do?

Thank You!

Comment: you store the result in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the issue too. What I do to fix it is instead of adding a UISearchBar in the UIToolBar via a UIBarButtomItem, I added the UISearchBar in a view (normal UIView) and added that view in the toolbar via the UIBarButtomItem. See the image below.

[image]

I don't know why, but this fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the TableView with Sorted items. Thats it.